# How to mention the bitwise or operator in CWEB?

Tags: cweb

While writing a CWEB program I wanted to write a comment like this:

```
@ If the option \.{-a} has been specified, the output files need to be opened in
append-only mode. Our program should also create the output file, thus the flags with
which we open the output file are either |O_RDONLY|O_CREAT|O_APPEND| or
|O_RDONLY|O_CREAT| as explained above.
```

It seems that CWEB does not like mentions of the bitwise-or operator `|` inside inner C contexts. Is there any way to mention a bitwise-or operator in a TeX section without manually reconstructing the output of CWEAVE?

Comment: Try using `@t$\vert$` as a replacement for `|`. That is, `...are either @t$\vert$O_RDONLY@t$\vert$O_CREAT@t$\vert$O_APPEND@t$\vert$ or
@t$\vert$O_RDONLY@t$\vert$O_CREAT| as...`

Comment: @Werner CWEAVE uses the macro `\OR` which is defined as `\let\OR=\mid` so the author can change the appearance of the bitwise-or. If I were to use the approach you describe, I would rather use this macro. Still, I hope there are better solutions.

Comment: So what is your ideal situation in terms of the input you supply? You can define your own TeX-macros using the `@f <name> TeX` directly, and then define `\<name>` to your liking.

Comment: @Werner `@f something TeX` with `\let\something=\OR` won't work because `something` will be treated as an identifier and thus subject to different spacing than the bitwise-or operator.

Comment: I'll repeat the question then: So what is your ideal situation in terms of the input you supply?

Comment: I'm sorry. It seems that I do not understand your question.

Comment: I'm not that familiar with CWEAVE so I may also be at fault here for misunderstanding. Do you want to maintain the current input `... are either |O_RDONLY|O_CREAT|O_APPEND| or ...` or are you okay with a different input, such as `... are either |O_RDONLY \OR O_CREATE \OR O_APPEND| or ...`?

Comment: @Werner Other forms of input would be acceptable. My workaround right now is to look at the CWEAVE output for the same input but with `&` substituted for `|`, then I replace all occurrences of `\AND` with `\OR` and finally I put the generated code into the source, circumventing CWEAVE.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I asked the following in a letter to Donald Knuth:

> Lastly, I started to use your CWEB system for a project to find out if literate programming is a style that suits me. So far, I like it very much! The only problem I am experiencing is that I haven't found a way yet to mention the bitwise-or operator | within a c-section. Is there special syntax for that or do I have to use <s>kludges</s> tricks with @t?

He gave this answer:

> Amazingly – after thousands of programs of which more than 100 must surely use bitwise or – I've never felt the need for that operator inside a comment! (I do have \vert defined in plain.tex so that I don't need | in math much.)
>
> There really is no way to “fool” the parser in ctangle/cweave, hence one cannot expect to just type any C code that includes the ‘|’ character. [That means || is problematic too]. My natural inclination, if I wanted ‘x|y’ within TEX code, would be $|x|\OR|Y|$ using the \OR from cwebmac.tex. [Actually I use different spacing in TAOCP …
>
> ```
> bitwise AND is \mathchardef\band="2026  
>         OR     \def\bor{\mathbin{\kern1mu\vert\kern1mu}}
> ```
>
> but \OR = \mid in cwebmac].
>
> If you need it more often or in quite general contexts, the best kludge I can think of is to substitute *another* binary operator that you aren't using, and let TEX make the switch:
>
> ```
> \def\bitor#1!{\begingroup\let\MOD=\OR#1\endgroup}
> Look at |x%y| and \bitor|x%y|! for example.
> ```
>
> comes out as
>
> > Look at *x* % *y* and *x* | *y* for example.